# What does it mean when no time specified beside the phone icon on Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

If a friend on Facebook isn't online, in the contacts bar you can see a phone icon beside the last time he's been on Facebook.

For example, if a contact's been online 16 minutes ago, I'll see beside his name: [image].

But what does it mean when there's no time specified beside the icon?

i.e. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your friend has completely logged out of Facebook on his or her mobile device and has chat set to "off" on their computer. FYI: This does not mean he or she is truly offline. He or she can still access Facebook via their web connection without any indication of activity or of a time stamp. Extensive personal experience avoiding a stalker has led me to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of bug. You can take a screenshot and report about this to Facebook here:

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/227370944025932

Source: [Facebook Help Team](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=580567771964322&answer_id=582837161737383)

Comment: The source link returns "The requested page could not be found."

Answer (score -3):

I noticed that even if they turn messenger to  "off " to avoid a stalker, if you go into your last conversation with them, it will show last active in the conversation under their name.

Comment: How does this answer the question?